# How do I obtain the unique member of an abstract base class in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

My Django models are organized as follows.

```
class Animal(models.Model):

  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class Cat(Animal):

  def meow(self):
    return "mreooooow"

class Dog(Animal):

  def bark(self):
    return "AARF!"

class EvilMonkey(Animal):

  def plot_world_takeover(self):
    return "muahahaha ..."
```

As you see, every "animal" has a unique first name within its own species. How do I filter for animals with the name "Ned"? `Animal.objects.filter(first_name="Ned")` apparently does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to go the route of [multi-table-inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). This would let you make queries on the base model.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

*Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common information into a number of other models. You write your base class and put abstract=True in the Meta class. **This model will then not be used to create any database table.** Instead, when it is used as a base class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child class.*

Nathaniel already mentioned the solution.

Comment: True, no database table is made, but I wish that it could still be queried.